# Facebook Domain Insights set up but not really working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I had set up FB Domain Insights quite a while ago, but I am not really seeing any data.

My setup:

- App of type "Website" setup with me and a couple other people as admins (this app is not activated; does it need to be?)
- Website's head includes: `<meta property="fb:app_id" content="(ID of that above app)" />`

When I go to https://www.facebook.com/insights/ , the site appears under Domain Insights.

When I click to view that, no matter what timeframe I choose, most of the sections are blank:

- Total Clicks shows 0 and reports no data found.
- Top Links *is* populated, and shows the top posts in the timeframe, with click metrics and an option to share them.
- People is empty and shows no data found.

I've tried looking around to see what it's supposed to look like, and I find only snippets of screenshots so it's difficult to ascertain; but it certainly looks like I'm not connecting properly.

Can anyone help me figure out what to tweak, where to look, even where I can find resources?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your app ID and a page where we can see how you've implemented domain insights?

Comment: Sure: http://www.reflexmath.com

App ID: 180301142178379

Comment: Thanks! Are you sure that you actually have clicks from Facebook to your site, since you've configured the domain insights?

Comment: I actually seems you might have been hit by this bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1463351263965222/

Comment: Yes, we get hordes of traffic; including a lot verifiably from Facebook. Thanks for the link, @Roemer . I hope it's that.